# No dependencies injection using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to write a Mockito test, unfortunately something goes wrong.
My classes are as follows:

My test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

public class TestClass {

    @Nested
    public class testingPersonClass{

        @InjectMocks
        public Person personOne = new Person("zakzak", 37);

        @Mock
        public  Hobbie hobbie = new Hobbie("Sport");

        @Test
        public void tesOne(){
            System.out.println("personOne "+personOne.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The class `Person`:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    int age;
    Hobbie hobbie;


    Person(String name, int age){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }

   //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name+" "+this.age+" "+ this.hobbie.toString();
    }
}
```

The class `Hobbie`:

```
public class Hobbie {

    String hobbie;

    public Hobbie( String hobbie ) {
        this.hobbie = hobbie;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.hobbie;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a

> java.lang.NullPointerException,

because the `hobbie` object has not been injected in the `personOne` object.

How can I solve that?

My Pom Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: When you mark a field with @Mock, you're not supposed to assign its value. The assignment is done by the call to  `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in your @Before method. As your code is written, there are no mocks in it, only real instances.

Comment: The same MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) will also inject your mocks as requested by @InjectMocks (I am not sure, it may be necessary for the fields to be public).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize Mockito mocks in the unit test with one of the following options:

### Option 1: In `@BeforeEach` (`@Before` in JUnit 4) method

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class TestClass {

    @Nested
    public class testingPersonClass {

        @InjectMocks
        public Person personOne = new Person("zakzak", 37);

        @Mock
        public Hobbie hobbie = new Hobbie("Sport");


        @BeforeEach
        public void init() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void testOne() {
            System.out.println("personOne " + personOne.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 2: Annotate your test class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` ( `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` in JUnit 4)

For this method, you have to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that I've commented out `init` method.

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Nested
    public class testingPersonClass {

        @InjectMocks
        public Person personOne = new Person("zakzak", 37);

        @Mock
        public Hobbie hobbie = new Hobbie("Sport");


/*
        @BeforeEach
        public void init() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
*/

        @Test
        public void testOne() {
            System.out.println("personOne " + personOne.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

### Useful links

You can find these articles helpful:

- https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations
- https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension

Comment: @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) solved my problem, using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) with JUnit4 gives an exception for some reason. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this, it works for me

you have to set the hobbie to personOne to link them, in your case hobbie and personOne are not linked

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {


    @InjectMocks
    public Person personOne = new Person("zakzak", 37);

    @Autowired
    public Hobbie hobbie = new Hobbie("Sport");

    @Test
    public void tesOne(){

        personOne.setHobbie(hobbie);
        System.out.println(personOne.toString());
        Assert.assertEquals("zakzak 37 Sport",personOne.toString() );
    }
}
```